# Google Tag Manager On Click event on Drop Down

Tags: google-tag-manager, event-tracking

Trying to figure out the best way to track on click events using google tag manager on an element that doesn't seem to change. this site: http://www.sleepcocktails.com/pages/faq has FAQ's where the use can click on a question which then expeands to show the answer. The goal is to understand which are the most clicked on questions so we can surface those earlier in the site.I think the best way to do this would be through click events, but as nothing really changes on the page i cant figure out what to target with google tag manager.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the following event tag

[image]

with the trigger to fire when the Click Class variable equals "text", like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Click Listener and configure your tag to only fire when someone clicks on a question e.g Click Classes equals text

and the set-up for your Event could be something like this:
Category: FAQ 
Action: clicks 
Label: {{element text}}